# Babylonian handbags - meaning?

Tags: ancient-history, religion, art, ancient-babylon

What is the meaning of “handbags” that Babylonian gods are often depicted carrying ?
[image]![god with handbag]

Comment: Welcome to History, AunAun! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. What has your research shown you so far? Where have you already searched? Please help us to help you. Where did you find that, what's the title, what is the larger picture showing? You may improve your question to comply with site guidelines with an [edit] and the help of [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: Assyro-Babylonian ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Met has one of these panels on display:
[image]

It also has an [interpretation of the image](https://www.metmuseum.org/art/collection/search/322595?sortBy=Relevance&ft=assyrian&offset=80&rpp=20&pos=86):

> The figure depicted on the panel is eagle-headed and faces left,
>   holding in his left hand a bucket and in his right hand a cone whose
>   exact nature is unclear. One suggestion has been that the gesture,
>   sometimes performed by figures flanking a sacred tree, is symbolic of
>   fertilization: the "cone" resembles the male date spathe used by
>   Mesopotamian farmers, with water, to artificially fertilize female
>   date-palm trees. It does seem likely that the cone was supposed to
>   hold and dispense water from the bucket in this way, but it is
>   described in Akkadian as a "purifier," and the fact that figures
>   performing this gesture are also shown flanking the king suggests that
>   some purifying or protective meaning is present.

Another depiction can be seen [here](https://www.ancient.eu/image/2711/) (I have cropped the image below to make it fit here):
[image]

This shows the same 'sacred tree' that was discussed in the Met image.
So we have an early depiction of... a bucket. Probably being used probably in some form of fertility rite.

Comment: And a wristwatch? :)

Comment: Probably a Babylonian style bracelet.

Comment: Since the wrist jewelry appears on both images, it is likely part of the priests' ritual wear or components, just like the buckets. Even the daggers and arm bands are repeated from image to image.

Comment: I'm just cracking up still at the thought of these pales as "handbags".